# Can't $emit scope variables

Tags: angularjs

My child controller can't $emit scope variables to the parent controller.

```
$scope.$on('state-change', function(e, data) {
    $scope.$emit('current-form-state', { email: $scope.email });
});
```

It does work if I just send a string literal, e.g.,

```
$scope.$on('state-change', function(e, data) {
    $scope.$emit('current-form-state', { email: 'john.doe@foo.com' });
});
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: In your code above there is an `'` missing after `'scope-change`

Comment: Can you provide a plunker/jsbin/jsfiddle with reproducible behaviour?  `$scope.email` may be undefined, etc etc. Typo is not the reason, I guess, as simple string is working fine.

Comment: Can I see `state-change` code?

Comment: Did you look in the console if there are errors? You have a syntax error. However, you say that the second line works, so I think that only this posts has the syntax error. The contents of the sent event have nothing to do with receicing the event (or not). This should work. If you mean that you are receiving `{ email: undefined }` in the parent controller, please clarify your question.